# Why am I not getting expected output when using String.format() function?

Tags: java, string.format

Why am I not getting expected output when using the String.format() function? The answer should be 123456789.123456789 right?

```
main()
{
    float a = 123456789.123456789f; 
    System.out.println(String.format("%f", a));   // Actual Output: 123456792.000000 
    System.out.println(String.format("%.4f", a)); // Actual Output: 123456792.0000 
    System.out.println(String.format("%.4f", a)); // Actual Output: 123456792.0000 
}
```

Comment: We can't tell you unless you tell us what you expect...

Comment: I have commented the answer at the end of the Statement shouldn't the answer be 123456789.123456789

Answer (score 2):

Float is 32bit. You just overflowed it and it was added to the integer part of number

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how it works? I mean how the overflow part was added to the Integer part?

Comment: Oh, it's very dirty business :D

You should find out it yourself in _Oracle docs_. Sorry.
With double it's more clearly. But float have mantissa, exponenta, and it's difficult to remember how it works.